# How do I create two vectors from an existing vector (of characters) in R?

Tags: r

so I just started using R and I have to struggle every now and then.
I have this vector of stimuli names such as:

```
1. abc1.jpg
2. abc2.jpg
3. bcd1.jpg
4. bcd2.jpg
5. cde1.jpg
6. cde2.jpg
```

now the first entry corresponds to the picture on the left, and the second on the right. I want to create two vectors named "left" and "right", in which the "left" vector would consist of the entries 1,3,5,7,9... (goes until 300) and the right being always the second entry of the same picture (2,4,6...)

How do I do this?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `str_split` in `stringr`.

Comment: or `strsplit` in base!

Comment: if `vec` is your vector, you could also do this: 
`lft <- vec[seq(1,length(vec), 2)]` and 
`rht <- vec[seq(2,length(vec), 2)]`

Comment: well, I tried but it didn't really work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vec <- 1:10 # an example vector with the numbers from 1 to 10

vec[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
# [1] 1 3 5 7 9

vec[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

The short index vector, e.g., `c(TRUE, FALSE)`, is recycled until its length matches the length of the vector `vec`.

Comment: Very nice.  I just tried it with `vec <- letters[1:10]` and it worked then too.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')

x.odd <- x[(1:length(x) %% 2)==1] ; x.odd
#[1] "a" "c" "e" "g"

x.even <- x[(1:length(x) %% 2)==0] ; x.even
#[1] "b" "d" "f" "h"
```